# How can i create a symlink(symbolic link) from an url in node js?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, node.js

I am trying to create a symlink by passing url in node js.

```javascript
let link="https://image.png******"
fs.symlink(link,__dirname+"\\folder\\symnotificationfeed2",'file',(err)=>{
if(err){
    console.log('errrr')
}else{
    console.log("\nSymlink created\n");
    console.log("Contents of the symlink created:");
}

           })
```

With the help of above code I am able to create a symlink in my local system but I am not able to access it or read the file.
I am using windows OS.
Please,Help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links can only point to other filesystem paths, not URLs. In Windows, this would include UNC paths for SMB-based file access (e.g. `\\server\share\image.jpg`) – but still not URLs, neither HTTP nor any other kind.

In general, if a location cannot be opened with `fs.open()`, then it cannot be a symlink target either.